# Attributes aren't auto completing in Android Studio XML

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I'm struggling getting attributes to autocomplete within the xml file. Normally when you create a new layout it will ask you to populate the layout width and height with either match_parent or wrap_content but i'm not getting any of those auto complete options. This also applies to other attributes such as text colour, strings etc.

I have tried invalidate cache and restart. Deleting .idea folder. Deleting cache folder.

[Auto Complete options not appearing after selecting attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2QG0.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Me too the same problem I have ..i wish someone can help